# How to get the object properties from click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML

```
<ol id="person-list"></ol>
<div id="person">
    <h2 id="person-name"></h2>
    <div id="person-age"></div>
    <img id="person-address">
</div>
```

JS

```
var persons = [{
    name: 'John',
    age: 54,
    address: '123 Main st.'
}, {
    name: 'Jack',
    age: 55,
    address: '456 Oak Ln.'
}];


$('#person-list').on('click', 'li', function () {
    alert('Hello'); // get other object info here?
});

var f = function () {
    for(var i = 0, len = persons.length; i < len; i++) {
        $('#person-list').append('<li>' + persons[i].name + '</li>');
    }
};
f();
```

When a person's name is clicked, it would need to grab the appropriate object's other properties and place them in the appropriate divs. For example, if John is clicked, John's age and address need to show in the divs below. How could I link the person's name in the list to its other property values? I thought about saving the value "i" with every name during the for-loop so there's a number associated with each name. Then somehow reference person[i].age when the "i"th value is clicked, but that sounded clumsy.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/98mocne5/1/)

Comment: Instead of Id use class. Id be unique

Comment: @JqueryKing I don't see duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data-*` attribute to store the index on the `li`.

1. Use `data-index` on the `li` when creating and store the index `i` on it
2. Use jQuery's [`data('index')`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) to retrieve the saved index on the clicked element
3. Use `$(this)` to access the clicked element in event handler

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/mv2hs1aj/)

```js
var persons = [{
  name: 'John',
  age: 54,
  address: '123 Main st.'
}, {
  name: 'Jack',
  age: 55,
  address: '456 Oak Ln.'
}];


$('#person-list').on('click', 'li', function() {
  // Get the clicked person's information
  var person = persons[$(this).data('index')];

  // Set info in the corresponding elements
  $('#person-name').html(person.name);
  $('#person-age').html(person.age);
  $('#person-address').html(person.address);
});

var f = function() {
  for (var i = 0, len = persons.length; i < len; i++) {
    $('#person-list').append('<li data-index="' + i + '">' + persons[i].name + '</li>');
    //                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
};
f();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="person-list"></ol>
<div id="person">
  <h2 id="person-name"></h2>

  <div id="person-age"></div>
  <div id="person-address"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Huge thanks. So my thinking was somewhat correct. Just didn't know how to implement. data-* attributes seem very powerful.

Comment: Welcome @MatthewMoon. Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `data-attribute` to the `<li data-person="id_of_the_person">` element and get it using `$(this).data("person")` in the click event handler and then get the person from your list

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `.index()` function to get the index of the name and then use that index to get the name from the persons array. Like this:

```
$('#person-list').on('click', 'li', function () {

    alert(persons[$(this).index()].name)
});
```

And here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98mocne5/3/). From there, you can do all the text manipulations you need.

```
$('#person-name').html(persons[$(this).index()].name);
$('#person-age').html(persons[$(this).index()].age);
$('#person-address').html(persons[$(this).index()].address);
```

Answer (score 1):

In event handler you can access the `index()` and then you can access the appropriate data.

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8k9838qz/)

Comment: This does seem like the easiest solution.